# AccountManagement create user return 'object already exists' exception

Tags: c#, active-directory, account-management

I'm trying to create a new UserPrincipal in a specific OU inside ActiveDirectory, and it returns an Exception with the message 'Object already exists'. (obviously) The user don't exists in that OU, and I'm testing its existence.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code throwing the exception:

```
public UserPrincipal CreateUser(string username, string pass,
        string givenName, string surname) {
    PrincipalContext context = this.principalContext;
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
    user.SamAccountName = username;
    user.UserPrincipalName = username;
    user.GivenName = givenName;
    user.Surname = surname;
    user.SetPassword(pass);
    user.Save();
    return user;
}
```

Edit 1: After unit tests, I found that the code is ok. I use this method in a lib (where I run the tests), that is called by another application, which has an Windows authentication mode enabled. Maybe the app is sending that authentication to AD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sAMAccountName must be unique across the enterprise.  You mention 'specific OU' when creating the user.  Is it possible you have another user with the same username/sAMAccountName in a different OU?

Comment: Yep. The user already exists in another OU, like you mentioned. My code verify if the user exists just in an specific OU, not the entire enterprise. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same error but didn't help much from the accepted answer above as in my case the issue is not due to `sAMAccountName` but due to `Name`. The account attempted to create had unique sAMAccountName but the name already exists which resulted in this error.

```
The object already exists.
```

Looks like the error can happen against more than one Active Directory account properties

- sAMAccountName
- Name

**Recommendation:**
Like in most of the cases, it is better to check for existence before creating a new entry.

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentries.find?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers,

Comment: Very helpful answer.  The `Name` property maps to the CN (Common Name) on the LDAP object.  The CN must be unique within the OU in which you're creating the account, or you'll get "object already exists".